# How to build and copy class library to output withot referencing it in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, mef

I am working on extensible web-application with plug-ins support. Each plug-in is located at separate class library project and implement some predefined `IPluginInterface` from common library. Application should load them on start using MEF. What I need to do is automatically build all plug-in projects in my solution and copy them into `bin` folder of my host project on every solution rebuild. Host application don't need to know anything about concrete plug-in implementations, so I don't want to add reference to these class libraries from it.

I know that it could be done with some command line script, but maybe there is easier way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: interesting, I always done with post-build steps

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any built in way. I currently use the following in the post build command line (Application being my host app):

```
XCOPY "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)*" "$(SolutionDir)Application\bin\Debug\*" /y
XCOPY "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)*" "$(SolutionDir)Application\bin\Release\*" /y
```